# Is there a drawback from using Drop Points?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I've noticed quite a few drop points that allow you to sell items. Is there a drawback to using these such as decreased sell value of items for the sake of convenience? I would like to utilize these as much as possible, but I'd need to know if going to a vendor is more profitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I've found, the prices for everything seem to be consistent regardless of the vendor (NPC or drop point) that you use.

Comment: I'd add that the only drawback if any is the limited eddy amount per location. So if you're selling off a ton of stuff, you'll need to make multiple visits to get the most out of it.